# jQuery force older version without changing jQuery selectors with no conflict

Tags: jquery

I have a page that has jQuery 1.6.2.  In some cases I load an app that requires jQuery 1.4.2.  I need to force the app to use the 1.4.2 version.  I am not able to change the selectors ($ to $$).

Is there a way to force the use of jQuery 1.4.2?

for instance onclick of an element I load the app.  Right before I load the app can I use getScript to pull the old version of jQuery?

Comment: It might make more sense just to make the whole site use jQuery 1.4.2, if possible. Are there bits on the site that require 1.6.2, or could you just downgrade the entire app?

Comment: @saalon: You should always _strive_ to be on the latest.

Comment: @mrchief: Clearly, but there are plenty of reasons why it's not always possible, and incompatibility with required libraries is one of them. I'm trying to see if it's an option on the table. I think you're better off using one, older version of a thing than loading two different versions until the library gets itself compatible with the new. But opinions aside, it's either an option or it's not, and it's good to know which.

Comment: Yes we are trying to get the site to latest version of jQuery.  Would rather not be stuck on 1.4.2 forever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can, check out this great article at http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/.

Something like this:

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.6.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>

<!-- revert global jQuery and $ variables and store jQuery in a new variable -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_6_2 = $.noConflict(true);

(function($){ 
   /* app code that uses jQuery 1.6.2 */ 
}(jQuery_1_6_2))

</script>


<!-- load jQuery 1.4.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>

<!-- revert global jQuery and $ variables and store jQuery in a new variable -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_4_2 = $.noConflict(true);

(function($){ 
   /* app code that uses jQuery 1.4.2 */ 
}(jQuery_1_4_2))

</script>
```

Comment: +1 duh i never considered using noconflict on jquery itself haha, always prototype and mootools when clients have those in use already.

Comment: I would like to leave the app and my selector alone.  keep both as $

Comment: Well, in that case, load the script as pointed out in the article and  use a wrapper function around the apps: `(function($){ /* app code that uses jQuery 1.6.2 */ }(jQuery_1_6_2))` and `(function($){ /* app code that uses jQuery 1.4.2 */ }(jQuery_1_4_2))`

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply trying to get the no Conflict rule to work and it's still not working for ya, there's a good reason. The methods posted above doesn't work unless you have a certain version.

Instead of adding the code to a existing Style sheet code in the HTML, give it it's own.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

I'm using this method with jQuery 1.4.2 and MooTools. Works like a charm.

Comment: Scratch that. Just noticed that the code just stops the jQuery 1.4.2 from working. >_<